# C# A problem with return T

Tags: c#

I have a method that converts a number from string to the T, e.g `int`

```
public static T GetItemIdFromUrl<T>(string itemName)
{
   try
   {
      ...
      int ad_id = int.Parse(stringNumber);

      return (T)(object)ad_id;
   }
   catch 
   {
      return (T)(object)-1;
   }
}
```

but as a result I have a hex code `0xffffffa5` instead of `91`. Why ?

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? Why are you trying to cast an integer to `T`?

Comment: Why is the method generic ? It will always fail if T is not int...

Comment: no, I cut the number from the string (the parameter) and then I cast it as a T (int, decimal, whatever I need)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: I know, but I dont want to use the same code (which cuts the number from the string and cast in as e.g int) many times

Comment: @Tony: Just make it return an `int`, and convert where you need to. The unboxing conversion here is not what you want.

Comment: you should be able to right click on the value in the watch window and from the fly out menu there is an option "Show hexidecimal" or somethig like that.  It will be checked in your case.  just uncheck it.  Eg: Debug > Windows > Watch 1 then right click on an entry and untick 'hexidecimal display'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your intention is to genericize the handling of different numeric types (e.g., `double`, `decimal`, etc.), this isn't the way to do it. When you *box* to `object`, and then *unbox* to `T`, [it will **only** work if the boxed type *actually is `T`*](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/the-difference-between-converting-and-unboxing-read-my-mind-compiler/). In other words, it will *not* perform a type conversion for you.

The only way (that I know of) to do the type conversion from `object` to whatever you want is by using the `Convert` class:

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(ad_id, typeof(T));
```

Even this is fragile, obviously (as it won't work if `T` is any non-numeric type); but at least it won't throw exceptions in pretty much all cases you're trying to cover. (Your method as it is currently implemented will throw for every `T` except `int`.)

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's hard to know for sure why it's returning 0xffffffa5 without knowing the input string, but your code is going to throw an exception if T is anything other than either `int` or a enum with an underlying base type of `int`. For example, it *will throw* if T is `double`. Your method isn't really generic - the value it's *trying* to return is always an `int`. Why is your method not just declared to return `int`? If you want to convert from `int` to some other type (`double`, `long`, whatever) just let that conversion be done on assignment. The unboxing conversion in your code *will not work* unless `T` is `int` or an appropriate enum (the latter of which seems unlikely).

One thing to note is that 0xffffffa5 is the bit pattern for -91. Is it possible that you've only seen that result in the debugger, and the result is meant to be -91 rather than 91?

Comment: in the parameter can be e.g the string 'myString-123'. In many other places, that numer will be used as int, decimal etc

Comment: @Tony: Your code is still going to fail. Listen to what *everyone* is saying: this method is broken. Completely broken. Making it generic is *not helping you*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what generics are and how they're supposed to be used.  The whole point of generics is to have the benefit of working on different types while not losing type safety which is what happens when you cast to `object`

That being said Jon Skeet is probably correct that it's probably the way the debugger is displaying the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something else where you show the ellipses (...):

```
   try
   {
      ...
      int ad_id = int.Parse(stringNumber);

      return (T)(object)ad_id;
   }
```

because I tried your sample and I get a return `int`.

You really don't have any way, currently, of ensuring your return is going to work. You method will rely on very specific information. Provide a bit more info where you have the ellipses and a better solution can be recommended. <strike>As Jon mentions, a nullable int? would be better. Test for the condition and if it isn't a correct return, you can check for `myInt.HasValue`.</strike>

I have been pondering a complete solution this problem and came up with the following:

```
static List<Type> numerics = new List<Type>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    numerics.Add(typeof(Decimal));
    numerics.Add(typeof(Double));
    numerics.Add(typeof(Int16));
    numerics.Add(typeof(Int32));
    numerics.Add(typeof(Int64));
    numerics.Add(typeof(Single));
    numerics.Add(typeof(UInt16));
    numerics.Add(typeof(UInt32));
    numerics.Add(typeof(UInt64));

    Console.WriteLine("StringNumber 55:  {0} {1}", typeof(int), GetItemIdFromUrl<int>("55"));
    Console.WriteLine("StringNumber 5B99:  {0} {1}", typeof(int), GetItemIdFromUrl<int>("5B99"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static T GetItemIdFromUrl<T>(string stringNumber)
{
    try
    {
        if (numerics.Contains(typeof(T)))
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(stringNumber, typeof(T));
        else
            return default(T);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException argEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception\r\n{0}", argEx);
        return default(T);
    }
    catch (FormatException formatEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception\r\n{0}", formatEx);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

From the 2nd `WriteLine` you will be able to see what happens if an invalid numeric is passed. Of course, I included the `Exception` messages just so you could see what they would return. It might not be a glamorous solution, but I think it is viable.

I also came up with this:

```
public static class GetNumeric<T>
{
    public static Func<string, T> Value = stringValue => (T)Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, typeof(T));
}
```

Although I would still wrap the call in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: I didn't mention `int?` at all. I used `int` at the end of a question, but I didn't intend to talk about nullable types at all.

Comment: @Jon: my fault...when I saw your post there is a question mark and I saw it as int?...I will revise...